# Can I use inner class variables in my method?

Tags: android

I have a question: can I use a inner class variable that is instantiated in a method in an another method?

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, android.view.View v, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int diffInDays=0;
            Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Masina m = (Masina) o;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected :" + " " + m, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String data=((Masina) image_details.get(position)).getData_fabr();
            Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
             SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
             String currData=df.format(c.getTime());

             try {

                 Date obj=df.parse(data);
                 Date obj2=df.parse(currData);
                 diffInDays = (int) ((obj2.getTime() - obj.getTime())/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

             } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             int years=diffInDays/365;
             int days=diffInDays%365;
             poz=position; 

             mar=((Masina) image_details.get(poz)).getMarca();
             mod=((Masina) image_details.get(poz)).getModel();
             nr=((Masina) image_details.get(poz)).getNr_inm();
             date=((Masina) image_details.get(poz)).getData_fabr();

             afisare.setText("Numar inmatriculare: "+((Masina) image_details.get(position)).getNr_inm());
             afisare.append("\nVarsta masina: "+years+" ani "+days+" zile");

        }
    });


}

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch(item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.edit:

        Toast.makeText(this, "Ai ales: " + getResources().getString(R.string.Editeaza), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent startNewAct=new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
            startNewAct.putExtra("marca",mar);
            startNewAct.putExtra("model",mod);
            startNewAct.putExtra("Nr.inm",nr);
            startNewAct.putExtra("Data",date);
            startActivityForResult(startNewAct,0); 


            return true;
```

i want to use vb mar in method onContextItemSelected. Someone help, please. Thank you very much.

Comment: have you tried to use it?

Comment: i had tried to use it, but it's null:(

Comment: so the method onItemClick was called, mar was initialised and after that when you use it in the method onContextItemSelected it is null?

Comment: yes, that's right...because it's initialized in inner method it doesn't have a value, so it's null

Answer (score 0):

U can initialized vb mar with public static in method.

Comment: solved the problem...it didn't had action at long click so that's why it didn't initialize. Thanks a lot you guys:*